# Available AI middleware

Tags: ai

A useful list of AI middleware.  Please provide URL, free/open-source or licenced, and brief description of abilites.

Format:

```
*Package* (License)
Link

Pros

Cons
```

Comment: I find it kind of sad that basically all AI middleware is pathfinding.

Comment: This is perfect timing, I just started a game project class this semester and my team is the "tools" team so we'll probably end up being the ones to write the bridge that integrates one of these into the game. :)

Comment: @Ricket forget middleware, you want to write it all yourself this one time, just so you know not to do it that way. :)

Comment: Is this even a proper question? Apart from the fact that is too broad and any possible answer is heavily determined by personal opinion, this seems to me that someone needed a list of AI middleware but didn't want to search himself and wanted other to do the job.

Answer (score 13):

**Recast/Detour** (ZLib license)

[Googlecode link](http://code.google.com/p/recastnavigation/)

Recast is a library to generate navigation meshes from polygon soups.  Detour is a pathfinding and spatial reasoning toolkit that works on navigation meshes.

Comment: Recast/Detour has to be the coolest AI middleware available - and then it's free - under the MIT license.
That's unbelievable. :)

Answer (score 8):

**[OpenSteer](http://opensteer.sourceforge.net/)** (MIT License):

> OpenSteer is a C++ library to help
>   construct  steering behaviors for
>   autonomous characters in games and
>   animation. In addition to the library,
>   OpenSteer provides an OpenGL-based
>   application called OpenSteerDemo which
>   displays predefined demonstrations of
>   steering behaviors. The user can
>   quickly prototype, visualize, annotate
>   and debug new steering behaviors by
>   writing a plug-in for OpenSteerDemo.

I've seen it used to great effect in simple games.

Comment: I've used it to great effect in a simple game prototype.

Answer (score 2):

There also MicroPather - an open source path finding library from the same guy who made TinyXML.

http://www.grinninglizard.com/MicroPather/index.htm

Comment: I've used this in several games--it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Havok AI (Commercial - not cheap)

http://www.havok.com/index.php?page=havok-ai

Havok is pretty good at physics, and has been offering behaviour, animation and other kinds of middleware for a while now.

Physics and AI is not easy to get to cooperate, especially animations, so save yourself some time and use Havok.

Highly recommended. :)

If you can afford it.

Pros:
Industry strength quality, proven technology.
Makes AI and Physics cooperate.

Cons:
Steep Price.

Comment: If you have used Havok AI, may I ask how much it cost you ?

Answer (score 0):

**SharpSteer**. (MIT license?)

https://github.com/boki/sharpsteer

SharpSteer is a C# port of OpenSteer. Like OpenSteer, the aim of SharpSteer is to help construct steering behaviors for autonomous characters in games and animation, with a current implementation focus toward Microsoft's XNA.

Answer (score 0):

AI.implant (Licensed)

http://www.presagis.com/products_services/products/ms/simulation/aiimplant/#

No idea if it's any good, I just remember getting some brochures from them at GDC a few years back, and it appears they're still around.

Comment: The company that made it shut down, so I don't know about "still being around". The support for it was picked up by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

xAItment (commercial)

http://www.xaitment.com/

Fairly new middleware suite providing everything from pathfinding to behavior / decision making systems. Haven't tried it myself, so I can't say if it's any good.

Answer (score 0):

Kynapse (commercial) is from what I understand the number 1 market share for pathfinding libraries. It's the oldest of the commercial AI middlewares around.

http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?siteID=123112&id=11390544

My experience with previous versions were that they were bulky with a terrible API and not very nicely implemented. We had tons of problems with it.

Now in their new version it seems they've changed data formats and some other radical changes, so maybe they've fixed the problems now.

It's also a commercial product and fairly expensive.

Answer (score 0):

NavPower (commercial)

http://www.babelflux.com/

My experience with it has been positive, although I haven't shipped any title with it yet. Most others I've talked to about it have had a similarly positive experience with it. API is easy to understand.

Fairly simplistic API, which can be a limitation.

Answer (score 0):

**Golaem** (Commerical)

http://www.golaem.com

I'll add to the list of commercial products Golaem (Full disclosure: I work for them).

Golaem Path is a real time 3D navigation library (path finding & reactive navigation / steering behaviors). It is not marketed for game development but could be used for a game.